# Python MySQL select query loop

Tags: python, mysql

Im currently trying to make an announcer which actually sends stuff when a new entry is made into the table.

Currently the only way I noticed is making a loop which asks every 1 second with a select query and the latest query id saved, if theres a new one.

I want to make it fast, but having 1 second queries everytime is kinda slowing everything down.

Is there another way?

Comment: One query per second slows down your system? How does it look like?

Comment: It doesnt, but its probably not the best way. Especially since its single-threaded so it might slow down other process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the better way is to use a **message queue**. Code your clients so that after they commit new data to the database, they post to a message queue. They don't have to post the full data to the queue, just an event to signal that it's time for the app to check for data.

Meanwhile, your announcer app can wait on the queue until there's an entry. So it's not polling the database, it's just blocking until something appears in the message queue.

There are many message queue implementations. For example:

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html
- http://www.snakemq.net/
- http://python-rq.org/

But the above requires that you change code in applications that write to the database. If you can't do that, an alternative that doesn't require any application changes is to use a Change Data Capture tool to monitor changes in the database by streaming the binary log. Here's an article about using CDC tools in this way: [MySQL CDC, Streaming Binary Logs and Asynchronous Triggers](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/09/13/mysql-cdc-streaming-binary-logs-and-asynchronous-triggers/).

Some people are tempted to write a MySQL trigger that signals the announcer app. *Don't try this.* Triggers fire before the transaction commits. So your announcer app would get notified about data before it can see the data. Also, the transaction might get rolled back, but the notification get sent anyway, so the announcer gets a false report of data it can never read.

For the latter reasons, if you use message queues, your writer apps must post to the queue only *after* they commit data to the database.